# Online "analogizing" services?

Tags: analog

Are there any online services that would allow one to use expensive analog gear remotely?

That I could use some sort of web interface, send tracks through the chain of my choice and even decide the settings that I want.

Does such thing exist?

Comment: I very much doubt it. If it did, would you expect it to be anywhere like real-time? If not, how many attempts at tweaking each device's parameters would you expect it may take before it sounded like you wanted it?

Comment: @Tetsujin Might not exist yet, but technically should be feasible, if the hardware has some kind of digital interface to it.

Comment: Kind of defeats the object as you would have to re-digitize the audio and deal with horrific latency issues. Additionally, each bit of classic analogue outboard gear would have to be fit with a digital controlled interface acessible from the web. Latency on this would be a killer..

Comment: We thought of doing it sometime ago,  but the drawbacks and obstacles are insane.  And we only wanted to hookup a studer and our console. Generally this is the reason people pay a lot of money for mastering.

Comment: If you want to layback any tracks comment here ill do it for free